# copying properties from json object to this scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can we rewrite this code using spread operator or simplify in some other way?

```
        this.activeCategory = json.activeCategory
        this.activeParent = json.activeParent
        this.openMenu = json.openMenu
        this.showMobile = json.showMobile
```

I am using this in `vue's mounted` hook

Comment: Are there any other properties in the json object?

Comment: json contains these 4 properties

Comment: Try: `Object.assign(this, json)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator paired with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const temp = { activeCategory, activeParent, openMenu, showMobile } = json;
Object.assign(this, temp);
```